# Fetch request to Flask backend response body is null with no-cors and fails without no-cors

Tags: python, reactjs, google-chrome, flask, cors

I am creating an app with stack React => Flask => MongoDB.
I want to have an easy to use development environment, so I host everything locally.

I work in Ubuntu 16

Running flask app from PyCharm on `localhost:5000`.
Writing React app with VS Code and running it with console `npm start` command, hosting it on `localhost:3000`.
I want to make a `GET` call from React app to Flask web api to retrieve some data from db into frontend.

Flask code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['test-database']
collection = db['test-collection']

@app.route("/orders/")
@cross_origin()
def GetAllOrders():
    all_docs = list(collection.find({}, {'_id': False}))
    print(all_docs)
    return jsonify(all_docs)
```

React code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(4);
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/orders/", { mode: "no-cors" })
  .then(results => {
    console.log(5);
    console.log(results);
    console.log(results.body);
  });
}
```

So whether I set mode `"no-cors"` or not the Chrome Developer Tools Network tab shows the `GET` call as successful and I can see the orders. Meanwhile, in the Console tab

when I send `GET` with `mode: "no-cors"` option I get Response object that has properties `bodyUsed: false` and `body: null`, so can not display the orders;

when I send `GET` without `mode: "no-cors"` option I get error:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:5000/orders/: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

And Network tab inspection shows only value for 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. Its value is 'http://localhost:3000'.

What am I missing? How to get those orders into my React application?

PS. I have CORS Chrome plugin installed and enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to disable the CORS chrome plugin. That plugin was the thing that was duplicating `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header values.